# How to convert DVDs to video files for Playstation3 - and not get "Corrupted data" error

Tags: video, dvd, encoding, handbrake

I want to save some DVDs to my Playstation3 hard drive for quick/easy access using Ubuntu 16.04, Handbrake and libdvd-pkg ([see step one of this guide](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-use-ubuntu-to-convert-dvds-to-mp4-4111375))

In Handbrake with the "Playstation 720p30" preset the encoding works fine and the resulting *.m4v video files can be played on my computer and look as expected.

I then copied the *.m4v video file to a (formatted FAT) USB drive and put the USB drive in the PS3. Under the PS3 video submenu the drive is detected but no videos are shown. By pressing triangle I can bring up the USB drive options which shows the video files as "Corrupted Data" when I try to open them.

One video file did play when accessed through the options menu (but not the standard menu system). However the quality was worse than I expected from 720p. This video file was from the same DVD and had been through the identical process as the other files.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Does anyone know of a process that can convert standard DVDs to playable video files on a Playstation 3?

Comment: DVDs are SD quality only. Handbrake or any other software can only upscale it with guesswork. But this is unrelated to the "corrupted files" issue. Have you already tried the same USB in Windows? You may find that Windows offers to correct that drive and then it will just work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The follow worked for me:

1. First used MakeMKV to extra DVD files. [How to install MakeMKV beta on Ubuntu](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/03/install-makemkv-play-dvd-blurays/).
2. In HandBrake Edit > Preferences unticked "**Use iPod/iTunes friendly (.m4v) file extension for MP4**":[image]
3. In HandBrake selected **Playstation720p30**
4. Saved outputted files to "Video" folder on USB drive.